# SQL Query - Count number of records where SUM is greater than current record

Tags: sql, woocommerce

I am writing a SQL query that SUMs the total sales by product, and I need a way to use the COUNT function to count the number of records whose SUM (totalsales) is greater than the current record.

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(product_gross_revenue) AS TotalSales, t.name as Category

FROM {prefix}wc_order_product_lookup c

LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON p.id = c.product_ID

LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID

JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id

JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id

WHERE (t.name='Cat A' OR t.name='Cat B' OR t.name='Cat C' OR t.name='Cat D' OR t.name='Cat E') 

GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
```

---

I would like to add a COUNT function to my select statement that counts the number of records where TotalSales is greater than the current record, but everything I've tried has failed.

---

Example, my current table looks like this:

| product_id | product_gross_revenue | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | Cat A |
| 2 | 150 | Cat B |
| 3 | 100 | Cat C |
| 1 | 150 | Cat A |
| 3 | 200 | Cat C |

What I would like my desired output to be:

| product_id | TotalSales | name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | Cat A | 2 |
| 2 | 150 | Cat B | 3 |
| 3 | 300 | Cat C | 1 |

Comment: Shouldn't your sum always be greater than that of a single row? Unless you've got negative revenues I don't think the problem is clear.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably doing a bad job of explaining what I'm looking for. I currently SUM and group by product ID so it shows me the total sales for each product. My goal is to count the number of products with a greater SUM for each product

Comment: There's also no point starting a left join but then connecting to a new table via inner join.

Comment: "Yeah, I'm probably doing a bad job of explaining what I'm looking for." -- Then [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites, make sure the statements are complete and compile, don't post just mere snippets), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data as ASCII or markdown table (see ["How can I create a table in a post?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)).

Comment: Tag the DBMS you're using and its version.

Comment: There's not much point in your LEFT joins; you inner join some more tables onto them so all the nulls introduced by the left will disappear again when the join condition fails for the nulls. Where clause would be more compact as IN

Comment: Sounds like RANK-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data as (<your query minus order by>)
select *,
    (
      select count(*)
      from data d2
      where d2.TotalSales > d1.TotalSales 
    ) as X
from data d1
order by TotalSales desc
```

If your conditions get more complicated then the subquery will work. It does sound like this will work also:

```
rank() over (order by sum(product_gross_revenue)) - 1 as TotalSales
```